# how to sum val stored in text field in octave figure

Tags: matlab, octave

may I ask for help in octave to do summation from textbox by click the button. enclose the form
[Octave Form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CNkwE.jpg)

so far my code like this:

```
MainFrm = figure(
    "position", [500, 500, 400, 200],
    "color", "blue"
);

TxtA = uicontrol (
   "style", "edit",
   "units", "pixels",
   "string", "INPUT VAL1 HERE",
   "position", [10, 100, 150, 38]
);

TxtB = uicontrol (
   "style", "edit",
   "units", "pixels",
   "string", "INPUT VAL2 HERE",
   "position", [200, 100, 150, 38]
 );

TxtC = uicontrol (
    "style", "edit",
    "units", "pixels",
    "string", "RESULT SHOW HERE",
    "position", [200, 50, 150, 38]
);

CmdSumm = uicontrol(
  MainFrm,
  "style", "pushbutton",
  "string", "SUMMATION",
  "units", "pixels",
  "position", [10, 50, 150, 38]
);

function Summation (hObject, eventdata, AddFrame)
  uicontrol(AddFrame);
  TxtC = TxtA + TxtB
end
```

what I want to do is:
user can put value in textbox1 and textbox2. 
after the user inputed the value on both textbox
user click or press the summation button 
to execute summation proses. 
the result then show / display in textbox3.

how to do this in octave?
thank you for your kind attention.

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest going through [Octave's GUI documentation](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/GUI-Development.html#GUI-Development) again. While not necessarily as comprehensive as they could be, there's a few things there that would have gotten you further along.

- First issue: your `Summation` function lacks references to the edit box objects, so it can't get the values
- Second issue: your pushbutton has no [callback](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/Callbacks.html#Callbacks), so clicking it won't do anything
- Third "issue": No idea what `AddFrame` is, or why it's an input to `Summation`

For the first issue, you'll want to use a function like [`guidata`](https://octave.org/doc/interpreter/GUI-Utility-Functions.html#XREFguidata) to store the handles to your graphics objects in a way that is accessible by the rest of the UI. To do so, store the outputs of your UI object creation calls to a structure, then save that structure to your main figure for later use. You can obtain the structure with another call of `guidata`

For the second issue, you need to specify `Summation` as the callback function for your pushbutton so it is executed on button press.

The updated code would look something like this:

```
function aGUI()
h.MainFrm = figure(
    "position", [500, 500, 400, 200],
    "color", "blue"
);

h.TxtA = uicontrol (
   "style", "edit",
   "units", "pixels",
   "string", "INPUT VAL1 HERE",
   "position", [10, 100, 150, 38]
);

h.TxtB = uicontrol (
   "style", "edit",
   "units", "pixels",
   "string", "INPUT VAL2 HERE",
   "position", [200, 100, 150, 38]
 );

h.TxtC = uicontrol (
    "style", "edit",
    "units", "pixels",
    "string", "RESULT SHOW HERE",
    "position", [200, 50, 150, 38]
);

h.CmdSumm = uicontrol(
  h.MainFrm,
  "style", "pushbutton",
  "string", "SUMMATION",
  "units", "pixels",
  "position", [10, 50, 150, 38],
  "Callback", @Summation
);

guidata(h.MainFrm, h)
end

function Summation(hObject, eventdata)
h = guidata(hObject);
C = str2double(get(h.TxtA, 'String')) + str2double(get(h.TxtB, 'String'));
set(h.TxtC, 'String', C)
end
```

Which functions as desired.

While not specifically Octave, I'd also recommend checking out [MATLAB's UI documentation](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/gui-controls-and-indicators.html). It's fairly comprehensive and the syntax should be more or less equivalent to what you'd find in Octave.

Comment: error: @Summation: no function and no method found. the button now show when I run the code...

Comment: @ghostsquare Octave does not support local functions in scripts. You need to either wrap your GUI initialization in its own function or have a separate `Summation.m` in the file path. I've edited an example of the former.

Comment: sorry for asking again.  just updated with your latest update and show error: set: invalid string property value for "string" execution error in graphics callback function. 
 
I try the code both octave for windows and octave for Linux.
both octave 4.2.1.....